# How to escape the `su -arch`?

Tags: bash, su

I assign an account name `arch`.

```
useradd -m -G users  arch
passwd arch
```

Now su into arch with command `su -arch`.

[image]

How to su into the account name `arch` with some kind of escape method?

Comment: Use : `su - arch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion is because you could login as root using

```
su - # There are no options in this case and the default login is root
```

But you're not supposed to do

```
su -arch #Anything the follows is an option
```

Since `a` is not a valid option you got an error

The right way could be anyone among the below

```
su arch 
su - arch # mind the space
su -- arch # The -- marks the end of options, gives way for non-options arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's few ways you can su with a login shell

```
su - arch
su -l arch
su --login arch
```

The problem is options processing with the command below - there is no `su -a` option

```
su -arch
```